# How to create a folder then save an image to the created folder using fileuploader in C# asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a simple program here wherein I can create a folder then save the an image to the folder created. The folder gets successfully created but I'm getting error into saving it to the newly created file. The error is:

> *The file could not be uploaded. The following error occured: 'N:/Kim's New Project/Safety Accident Report/File Uploader 2/File
>   Uploader 2/Uploads/asdsa' is a physical path, but a virtual path was
>   expected.*

Can you please check my code. Please help. Thank you.

```
protected void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (FileUpload2.HasFile)
            {
                try
                {
                    if (FileUpload2.PostedFile.ContentType == "image/jpeg")
                    {
                        if (FileUpload2.PostedFile.ContentLength < 512000)
                        {
                            string strpath = @"N:\Kim's New Project\Safety Accident Report\File Uploader 2\File Uploader 2\Uploads\" + txtName.Text;
                            if (!(Directory.Exists(strpath)))
                            {
                                Directory.CreateDirectory(strpath);
                                lblResult.Text = "Directory Created";
                                if ((Directory.Exists(strpath)))
                                {
                                    string filename = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload2.FileName);
                                    FileUpload2.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(strpath) + filename);
                                    Label1.Text = "File uploaded successfully!";
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                lblResult.Text = "Already Directory Exists with the same name";
                            }


                        }
                        else
                            Label1.Text = "File maximum size is 500 Kb";
                    }
                    else
                        Label1.Text = "Only JPEG files are accepted!";
                }
                catch (Exception exc)
                {
                    Label1.Text = "The file could not be uploaded. The following error occured: " + exc.Message;
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
FileUpload2.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(strpath) + filename);
```

try

```
FileUpload2.SaveAs(Path.Combine(strPath, filename));
```

you already know the physical save path - no need for Server.MapPath

Answer (score 0):

Try..

```
string strpath = Server.MapPath("~/Test");
if (!(Directory.Exists(strpath)))
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory(strpath);               
}
```